# Proper way to create an image with paintCompnent method - Java

Tags: java, user-interface

I am working on an assignment and I need to first create a simple GUI that displays a picture/gif on it. However I need to use the paintComponent method, which I am struggling with.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
import javax.swing.*; import java.awt.Graphics.*;

public class HelloGIF extends JFrame {

    image1 =Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage("C:\\Users\\carlo\\Documents\\Carlo's Documents\\ITEC 2610\\Java Files\\HelloGIF\\BT-Thumbsup.gif");

    public HelloGIF(String title) {
        super(title);
        setBounds(75,75,750,500);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.drawImage(image1, 200, 150, 50,50,this); 
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){

        System.out.println("Initializing...");

        HelloGIF myApp = new HelloGIF(String.join("+",args));
        myApp.setVisible(true);

    }
}
```

At the moment compiling generates an "identfier expected" on "C:\Users\carlo\Documents\Carlo's Documents\ITEC 2610\Java Files\HelloGIF\BT-Thumbsup.gif", pointing to the I in 'HelloGIF'. what declaration should I add? Am I on the right track or am I totally off?

Comment: `image1 =Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage(...)` should be `Image image1 =Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage(...)`.  I hope this isn't an animated gif, you might be in for some fun times if it is

Comment: I would also encourage you to make use of [`ImageIO`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/loadimage.html) to load images, but this doesn't support animated GIFs and you'd have to make use of [`ImageIcon`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/ImageIcon.html) instead